# SSRS Report - Multi Valued Parameters Executed One at a Time

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am new to SSRS and I'm wondering how I can execute a SSRS report multiple times for different parameter sets where the results will be in a single document.

For example, if there is a control table that lists regional managers, the stores, and individual employees like:

### RM    |   Store    |   Employee

RM1   |   Store 1  |  Employee 1
   RM1   |   Store 2  |  Employee 2
   RM1   |   Store 2  |  Employee 3
   RM1   |   Store 2  |  Employee 4
   RM2   |   Store X  |  Employee 5
   RM2   |   Store X  |  Employee 6
   RM2   |   Store Y  |  Employee 7
   RM2   |   Store Y  |  Employee 8

I want the user to be able to select a single regional manager and the report to be run for all employees under that regional manager.  Currently the report can be executed for a single employee and we could programmatically call the report for each employee individually, but that produces a document for each employee and we want all the results for a regional director to be in a single document just on different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome StackOverflow!

Want you want to do is pretty simple. You already have your report that shows a single employee, we can use this as a subreport.

Let's assume your current single employee report is called `SingleEmpReport` and it takes a single parameter `empID`. Let's leave this for now as thats all we need..

Now you need to create a new report that will act as the main report and will loop thru you employees.

So..

- Create a new report say, `ManagerReport`
- Create a new parameter called `pManager` (we'll come back to this later to improve it but just creating the parameter will suffice for now)
- Create a new dataset called, say, `dsEmployees`. Set the dataset query to be something like

  `SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID 
      FROM myControlTable 
      WHERE ManagerID = @pManager
      ORDER BY EmployeeName`

**Note: parameter names are case sensitive. It must be spelled exactly as your report parameter and preceeded by an @ symbol**

- Next, add a tablix to your report body, a List will do as we only need one column and one row but a table would also have worked.
- Make the list as wide as your report body, the height does not matter so leave it at the default height.
- Set the dataset property of the list/tablix to `dsEmployees`
- In the only 'cell' in the list, right-click and insert a subreport
- Right click the subreport placeholder and set the subreport property to `SingleEmpReport` or whatever your original single employee report is called.
- On the parameters tab, Add a new parameter, click the left drop down and choose your `empID` parameter (this is what you defined in your original report so choose the correct parameter from your original report.)
- On the right drop down, choose `EmployeeID`. This is the column from the dataset we created containing a list of employees for the selected manager. As the list/tablix is bound to the `dsEmployees` dataset we can choose any field from it to pass to our subreport.

I'm doing this from memory but I think that's basically it. Run the `ManagerReport`, enter a manager ID (RM1 etc) and you should get a subreport for each employee.

If you want to add page breaks between each employee, select the list/tablix and look at the row groups panel at the bottom of the screen. You will probably see a 'details' group. Right-click this, choose 'group properties', then click page breaks and choose 'between each group'.

You can also make this a bit better by providing a drop down list of managers.

To do this just add a new dataset, say, `dsManagers`, set the query to something like

```
`SELECT DISTINCT RM 
    FROM myControlTable 
    ORDER BY RM`
```

Now right click your report parameter (`pManager`) and set it's available values to a query then choose your dataset. Set the value to whatever you want the `dsEmployees` dataset query to use and the label to whatever you want your user to see.

You should now have a drop down list of managers.

Hopefully I've not missed anything significant out (it's past midnight here) and you'll be able to work thru these steps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your report consists of just a table/matrix, you can add an additional row group that groups by employee, using a page break between the groups.

If the design of your report contains more elements, you could place these elements inside a list and group that list by employee (also with page breaks).

Comment: Unfortunately the report is more complex than a single table/matrix, so the groupings with page breaks won't work.

Comment: Ok, and what about the second option I was talking about: a *list*?